# AJAX with Jquery in ASP.MVC2

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, ajax

I'd like to get something via Ajax and put it into

What i have to return from Controler Action to put this into that DIV? Right now i had standard ASP.MVC view as result...

```
public ActrionResult MyAction() {
   return View();
}
```

and in javascript i have:

```
$.get(<url to controler action>, null, function(data) { $(#result).html(data); })
```

Typical action associated with MyAction, with reload page works perfect. but when i do $.get(...) i got whole page in "data" (content and master page). How can i get only part of View(), without MsterPage??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could return a partial:

```
public ActrionResult MyAction() 
{
   return PartialView();
}
```

Where you have `MyAction.ascx` partial containing some HTML fragment:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl" %>
<div>Hello</div>
```

And you [inject this partial using an AJAX call](http://api.jquery.com/load/) into the `#result` div:

```
$('#result').load('/home/myaction');
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use

```
public ActrionResult MyAction() {
    var stuff = new { id = 1, name = "test" }; //or whatever stuff you need in your page
    return Json(stuff);
}
```

from your ActionResult method.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to a json response, you can return the html. All you need to do is to filter and get the html that you want to append from the 'data' variable.

```
$.get(<url to controler action>, null, function(data) { 
              $('#result').html($(data).find('#partOfViewID').html()); 
              });
```

Answer (score 0):

that's not a problem with jquery / ajax.   you need an action that returns a partial view.   not one that returns a view with a master page.

you can use this part:

> $.get(, null,
>   function(data) {
>   $(#result).html(data); })

but your action will have to have a partial view associated with it, not a regular view with a master page.

so make a new action. add a view to it, check the partial view checkbox. and put whatever you want to be reloaded in that partial view.